# How to build a High-Order Component that has knowledge of it's children

Tags: reactjs, high-order-component

I want to create a [High-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that handles the way it's children get rendered according to a passed `permissions` property.

Here is what I have right now:

```
import React from "react";
const PERMISSION_VIEW = 1;
const PERMISSION_EDIT = 1 << 1;

// A High-Order Component that adds visual feedback according to the
// permissions prop that gets passed to it    
function withPermissions(Component) {
  const wrapper = (props, ref) => {
    const { permissions } = props;

    // Do not apply any permissions handling if we don't
    // pass any permissions
    if (permissions === undefined) {
      return <Component {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
    }

    const propChanges = [];
    let afterElements = [];

    if ((permissions & PERMISSION_VIEW) === 0) {
      // We'll assume that the data is already filtered from the server
      afterElements.push(
        <span key={0}>You do not have permissions to view this field</span>
      );
    }

    if ((permissions & PERMISSION_EDIT) === 0) {
      afterElements.push(
        <span key={1}>You do not have permissions to edit this field</span>
      );
      propChanges.push({ readOnly: true, disabled: true });
    }
    props = Object.assign({}, props, ...propChanges);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Component {...props} forwardedRef={ref} /> {afterElements}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  // Give this component a more helpful display name in DevTools.
  // e.g. "ForwardRef(logProps(MyComponent))"
  const name = Component.displayName || Component.name;
  wrapper.displayName = `withPermissions(${name})`;

  return React.forwardRef(wrapper);
}
```

And here is an example use

```
function Data(props) {
  return props.value || "";
}
Data = withPermissions(Data);

const ref = React.createRef();


const App = () => <Data permissions={0} ref={ref} value="111" />;
console.log(App);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This [is working](https://codesandbox.io/s/52ryny3v2n) but what I want to do is have extra behaviour according to the type of the component

- For example if it's an `input` element and have no edit permissions make the field `readonly`
- If it's a `textarea` element and have no view permissions make the field `readonly`
- If it's a link and has no view permissions remove it's `href` prop
  etc...

Is this thing even possible? Is there a better way to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I was thinking this wrong. It shouldn't be the HOCs job to handle it's wrapped controllers differently. The wrapped component should be compatible with the 'interface' of the HOC instead.

So what I did:
Left the HOC as-is.
Made sure that all the components that I wrap with the HOC handle their readOnly and disabled props instead, but without permission knowledge.

If JS was a typed language I'd also create an interface for that, but this will have to do for now :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing conditional property like the following:

```
<input type="text" readonly={props.value && PERMISSION_EDIT} />
```

So now, if user has no `PERMISSION_EDIT`, then `readonly` will be there.

Thanks [@dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) for clearing up about the bit operator.

Comment: I think you don't understand that `PERMISSION_EDIT` is not boolean.

Comment: Yea, as I said you don't really understand that it's a bit mask.

Comment: Yeap, I also don't understand why OP couldn't figure out that he can do simply `readOnly={props.value & PERMISSION_EDIT}`.

Comment: This is left shift (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift) used for bit operations.

Comment: Well it's not used very often in daily web development. But whatever, this approach will work. Cheers!

Comment: The question is not "how to make the input readonly" rather than "how to tell if the component is an input element".

But after some thought I think I'm going to do it the other way around, by assuming that the component has a `readOnly` prop enforce the interface somehow